# Dynamic checkbox on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an c# aspx web application that is meant to generate most of its components on the fly. There is this GridView that is meant to display some check boxes.

The wierd thing is that it does not show the component on run but the namespace, i.e. `System.UI.Webcontrols.CheckBox`.

I need to see the checkbox; how can this be fixed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

[aspx.cs]

namespace ChkBoxOnGridView
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateGridView();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(cb);
            }
        }

        private void PopulateGridView()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.Columns.Clear();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DTA", typeof(System.String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Is Visible", typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)));

            CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
            chkbx.Checked = true;

            DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
            row1["DTA"] = "Some Text";
            row1["Is Visible"] = chkbx;
            dt.Rows.Add(row1);

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                BoundField bField = new BoundField();
                bField.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                bField.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                GridView1.Columns.Add(bField);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create each object individually in each row using the [GridView.RowdataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).

You can add it using the `e.Row.Cells[]`

But, to get sure that you're creating it in the right place, you have to check in this event that you are in a row which is not a header or footer, or pager. You do this by checking the [GridViewRow.RowType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx) of the e.Row and check if it's `DataRow`

```
 void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    // cb.id = ... and other control setup
    // add your control here:
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(cb);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me a working model based on my code, am quite new to c#.

Comment: There's nothing difficult in what I'm showing you. I will make it clear, however, that you simply have to DataBind your CustomerGridView, and handle its RowDataBound event with a code like the shown. You can access the data associated to each row casting e.Row.DataItem to your model class, so that you can acces its properties easily to decide how you add your control.

Comment: How do I make cb to take the checked status of chkbx and also remove the third column that's a repetition of the first column? I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb i would say that you can't hold a control in a DataTable. The [Is Visible] should be a boolean value

I'd add columns in the On Init event, using a template column. See this SO question:
[Adding dynamic columns to an ASP.NET Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234935/adding-dynamic-columns-to-an-asp-net-gridview)