# Create a dynamic column in gridview while page upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I want to add a column to my gridview while page is uploading.

My gridview takes his data from SQL static tables... and I want to add a column which contains the number of the row (1,2,3...)

Part of my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="InjuryScenario_id" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource30" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_OnSelectedIndex" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
     CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
     BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellSpacing="1">
   <Columns>
       <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryScenario_id" HeaderText="מספר תרחיש" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InjuryScenario_id"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Cause_name" HeaderText="מנגנון" SortExpression="Cause_name" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="City_name" HeaderText="יישוב" SortExpression="City_name" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Place_name" HeaderText="מקום" SortExpression="Place_name" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryDay" HeaderText="יום" SortExpression="InjuryDay" Visible="False"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryMonth" HeaderText="חודש" SortExpression="InjuryMonth" Visible="False"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="InjuryYear" HeaderText="שנה" SortExpression="InjuryYear" Visible="False"/>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="תאריך">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%#(int)Eval("InjuryDay")+"/"+ Eval("InjuryMonth")+"/"+ Eval("InjuryYear") %></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I've tried to use this method:

```
protected void Btn_AddCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
    tf.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "Col1", "Int32");
    tf.ItemTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "Col1", "Int32");
    GridView1.Columns.Add(tf);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234935/adding-dynamic-columns-to-an-asp-net-gridview?rq=1

Comment: my visual aint recognise "GridViewLabelTemplate"